# How to increase carbon-cache nofile limit on Debian 7?

Tags: debian, file-descriptor, graphite, ulimit

I'm running Graphite 0.9.12 on a Debian 7 server.

Recently I found errors in carbon-cache's log, saying "too many open files". According to carbon-cache's website, I need to increase nofile limit for carbon-cache. http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/carbon-daemons.html

So I increased both system wide and per-process limit:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
5000000
```

And in /etc/security/limits.conf

```
* hard nofile 1000000
* soft nofile 1000000
root soft nofile 1000000
root hard nofile 1000000
www-data soft nofile 1000000
www-data hard nofile 1000000
```

Using ulimit command, I can confirm root/me/www-data's file limit has been increased.

I restarted carbon-cache multiple times. However, the per-process file limit for carbon-cache is not increased, still at 1024:4096

```
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```

I'm using /etc/init.d/carbon-cache start script to restart carbon-cache, `sudo service carbon-cache restart` (or stop and then start)

The script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          carbon-cache
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: initscript for runit-managed carbon-cache service
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Opscode, Inc. <cookbooks@opscode.com>

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="runit-managed carbon-cache"
NAME=carbon-cache
RUNIT=/usr/bin/sv
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if runit is not installed
[ -x $RUNIT ] || exit 0

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions


case "$1" in
  start)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC " "$NAME"
        $RUNIT start $NAME
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  stop)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
        $RUNIT stop $NAME
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  status)
        $RUNIT status $NAME && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  reload)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
        $RUNIT reload $NAME
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  force-reload) ................ SO ON
```

Does anyone know how can I make carbon-cache apply my new nofile limit? Should I modify the start script or do something else?

===============================================================

Update:

I found another file may be related in my system. `/etc/sv/carbon-cache/run`.

Originally, the content shows as:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1
exec chpst -u www-data -l /opt/graphite/storage/carbon-cache.lock -- /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py --pid /opt/graphite/storage/carbon-cache-a.pid --debug start
```

I edited the file to:

```
#!/bin/sh
ulimit -n 999999
exec 2>&1
exec chpst -o 999999 -u www-data -l /opt/graphite/storage/carbon-cache.lock -- /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py --pid /opt/graphite/storage/carbon-cache-a.pid --debug start
```

Now in /proc/pid/limits, both soft and hard limit are 999999.

Answer (score 0):

> With the ulimit command, you can change your soft limits for the
>   current shell environment, and hard limits if running as root.

Scripts in init.d start with new shell env (session) the ulimit must be applied once again. You could add to `/etc/init.d/carbon-cache` before `case` statement something like:

```
ulimit -n 999999
```

This will set for current (`init.d start`) session new limit every start/restart/reload/whatever. Limits are inherited from a parent process to its child processes, so carbon-cache will be affected as well.

**edit**

1. set the hardlimit with `ulimit -H`
2. is it supervisor? if so, also add [minfs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#supervisord-section-values) in `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` in section `[supervisord]`.

`minfds=10000`

Comment: I added ulimit -n 10000 to start script. However when I'm checking new pid's limits, (/proc/pid/limits) it's still showing as 1024/4096, but not 10000. And ideas?

Comment: try to increase hardlimit with `ulimit -H 10000`

Comment: Using ulimit -H didn't help as well. However, as I looked into some other possibly related files, I found this one "/etc/sv/carbon-cache/run". Inside the "run" file, it shows "exec chpst -u www-data -l /opt/graphite/storage/carbon-cache.lock -- /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py --pid /opt/graphite/storage/carbon-cache-a.pid --debug start" So I searched command chpst, and found a -o option to set file limit. I added -o 99999 to "run" file, and restarted carbon-cache. Now both soft-limit and hard-limit are 4096. It seems the -o option raised soft limit, but not hard limit. Any way to fix this?

Comment: you wrote that you edited /etc/security/limits.conf. have you rebooted the system?

Comment: and `chpst` can only change process (not session) conf/state within hard limits. It is impossible to change hard limits with it.